# Я хочу чтобы из нескольких списков, выбрались те значения, что не входят в последний список

Tags: python, list

Я хочу чтобы из нескольких списков остались те значения, которые не входят в последний - проверочный список.
Например, у меня есть 3 списка - [2, 3, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3, 4] и [3, 3, 3].
В этом примере должно вывестись - 2, 2, 3, 2, 4.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Куда делась еще одна двойка?

Comment: Всмысле? Все двойки там.

Comment: Нет, не все. Одной не хватает. Почему?

Comment: И откуда взялась тройка?

Comment: @Эникейщик Видимо, это четвертая тройка, которой нет в последнем массиве.

Comment: сори. Дейвствительно не хватало одной двойки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

одну двойку потеряли.

```
l1 = [2, 3, 3, 2]
l2 = [2,3, 3, 4]
l3 = [3, 3, 3]


for i in l3:
  if i in l1:
    l1.remove(i)
  elif i in l2:
    l2.remove(i)

x = list(map(list, zip(l1,l2)))

l = []
for i in x:
  for j in i:
    l.append(j)

if len(l) < len(l1+l2):
  longest = l1
  if len(l2) > len(l1):
    longest = l2
  l.append(*longest[int(len(l)/2):])
print(*l)
```

`2, 2, 2, 3, 4`